# cp or rsync, is cp really worth it?

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, utilities, cp

I hope this does not count as a question without a real answer, as I can't seem to find a good reason to use `cp(1)` over `rsync(1)` in virtually all circumstances. Should one typically favour `rsync` over `cp`? Is there any good guideline for their use?

- `rsync`: Transfers the diffs, it can use compression, it can be used remotely (and securely), it can be restarted despite an interruption, even during the transfer of a single large file. '
- `cp` : Perhaps it's just simpler to use? Is it faster than rsync?

Comment: Sometimes the overhead of comparing is far more effort than simply copying the bytes blindly.

Comment: Same question with better answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cp` is a part of coreutils, therefore it is present everywhere. Furthermore, it primarily was designed to copy files inside one computer.

`rsync` isn't a part of coreutils, it isn't present even on the default environment. Moreover it was primarily designed to transfer files over network. Also `rsync` has more dependencies comparing to coreutils, however this difference doesn't make a big sense.

PS: By the way, the CPU usage is still matters on the embedded systems.

Answer (score 7):

The main reason you don't want to use `rsync` for every copy operation, is becasue `rsync` has calulating overhead.  Before data transfer actually starts, `rsync` scans all the files.  Then before each file, a comparison is made.  This overhead is not insignificant, even with the fast CPU's available in 2012.  I do these type of transfers all the time, and on pretty decent sized servers, once you start dealing with gigs of data the overhead can be time consuming.

I'm not saying don't use `rsync`, not at all, use `rsync` anytime you can save some transfer time.  Just don't use `rsync` when `cp` could accomplish the same thing.

What I usually do, first bring over the data using regular copy methods. Then `rsync` for subsequent changes, which is when those diffs can be leveraged.

Comment: Is it a large price to pay, given how powerful our processors are today?

Comment: Large is subjective, and would change depending on the number of files vs size of data vs IO.  My main point would be, it's not insignificant regardless of today's processors.  One thing to remember today's processors, still must deal with today's data.

Comment: Agreed. CPUs don't get faster in a vacuum. One of the best reasons we have for GHz CPUs is gigabit networking: a slower CPU simply cannot keep an I/O pipe that big full. Computers tend to be as well balanced as we know how to make them. Take away some CPU power, and some of the I/O capacity goes idle. Increase the I/O demand, and the CPU ends up idling more, waiting on I/O.

Comment: the scan of all files before transfer is not enabled by default anymore, and the payoff of transferring less data is usually much greater than the comparison overhead

Comment: @xeruf, I wasn't speaking about a situation, where you have a payoff. If there is any amount of matching files on the other end, use `rsync`.  I was only speaking about when you are making the initial copy, which I would not use `rsync` for.  If it is on the same fs, I'd likely use `cp -a` for convenience.  If it was crossing partitions, disks, or network, I'd use a tarpipe.  After that initial transfer, I would use `rsync` going forward.

Comment: Didn't know about `cp -a`, thanks! Though, as soon as the files to copy become bigger I prefer `rsync` for the progress meter. I don't see any meaningful downside on a modern computer to always using it.

Comment: though it might be possible to get a rough indication of progress with `cp -v` into https://git.jfischer.org/xeruf/dotfiles/src/branch/main/.local/bin/scripts/rewrite

Answer (score 4):

I would expect `cp` to use less *CPU* when copying locally because it doesn't use diffs whereas `rsync` can reduce *writes* when using diffs. Compression should be avoided locally because you have to read and write the whole file/diff anyway and it requires additional computations.

Comment: So, it all boils down to CPU cost or I/O cost

Comment: @soyuz, that is true for data which has changed, in reference to other data. The smaller the diff, the more `rsync` is preferred.  But when their is no diff, `rsync` is only bringing overhead without extra benefit.

Comment: @TechZilla I think you mean, when there's nothing in common.  If there is no diff, rsync will just end early 'cause there's nothing to copy, making it far more preferred.

Comment: @Izkata: There's at least one way for `rsync` to have twice the I/O overhead for two identical files as compared to blind `cp`: a changed modification time. You'd have to give `--size-only` to fix this. The only other way I can see around this would be for `rsync` to rely on filesystem checksums, but for most filesystems they're not very good statistical predictors of identity.

Answer (score 4):

Quite apart from overheads in the case of a large or nonexistent diff, `rsync` does not appear to have an equivalent of `cp --reflink=always`, which can save an enormous amount of data if copying within a filesystem that supports it (it creates copy-on-write copies, so data in common between the original and the copy (which is, of course, initially all of it) is stored only once).  `rsync` is, however, better at *updating* CoW copies, using `--inplace`.